# Commodore Amiga 600 Software Failure. "Error: 8000 0004 Task: 000026D0"

Tags: amiga, floppy-disk, rom, amiga-600

Software Failure on Commodore Amiga 600 when I insert a floppy in drive.

> **Software Failure. Press left mouse button to continue. Error: 8000 0004 Task: 000026D0**

Independent from the floppy I insert. Can't identify the error: is it a ROM error, or a floppy drive error? A virus, maybe (even if I think it's not plausible)?

[image]

Comment: IIRC 8000 are error coded from startup ROM during initialisation, before any exec code is started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: It's an illegal instruction error.

Most likely you're trying to boot code for a different CPU (like an 68020 or above).

---

Details for (early) errors are defined in the [exec/alerts.h](http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Includes_and_Autodocs_3._guide/node065B.html) file (*1,2).

`80` has the high bit set indicating a machine stoping error and `00` indicating CPU errors directly taken from the coresponding [exception](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~sexton/WWWPages/exceptions.html).

`00` would be the general error/error class (here unspecified)

`0004` means illegal instruction.

The 'Task' value is just the address it happened.

---

*1 - Here [the list](http://www.amigahistory.plus.com/guruguide.html) stripped of all programing noise

*2 - Another [list with more error codes](http://www.amibay.com/showthread.php?14510-Amiga-Error-Codes), mixing various sources

Comment: Probably worth adding that since the address is in the Chip RAM most definitely is not in the Kickstart.

Comment: I checked and the CPU inside the A600 has been not modified/upgraded... it's the pure Motorola 68000... and the disks are the same of the A500... so they should work on the A600 as well...

Comment: @FrancescoB Well, the CPU thinks otherwise and fires an illegal instrucion exception.  Ofc, it doesn't have to be software made for a later CPU. Data can be corrupted as well. It doesn't change the fact that all this message tells for certain is that an illegal (unknown) instruction has occured. So you might want to do classic debugging - like using the disks on another, similar configured A600 - or maybe even a 500 first.

Answer (score 1):

That may be a floppy drive defect, since it errors on all your disks. Read errors in the bootblock may cause the illegal instruction.

Comment: Bootblocks are checksummed, it's unlikely the ROM would just read and execute bad data.